# Laravel 5.1 Auth not consistent

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-authorization

I am working on a project and did the Laravel 5.1 Authentication. I followed the Documentation. I only have one user, no registration.

Now, when I protect routes I do it this way:

```
Route::group(array('middleware' => 'auth', 'prefix' => '/admin'), function() 
{ ... }
```

Then the Login-Form comes back, I authenticate and it is working. But now, when I refresh the page (or go to other admin-pages) sometimes I am logged out and redirected to the login-form again, sometimes I get a "Whoops, looks like something went wrong.", and sometimes it is working for some requests.

I have no idea why and when it is happening. I followed [this documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication)

When I was working with Laravel 4.* everything was fine.

Did someone have the same problems ?

Comment: pleasse give us all the info you can give, the "whops error" can you give us what error? look at the logs and see what trigger the error, did you change the auth controller or user model? if yes how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed - When i logged in, angular was loading like 300 items. Every item tried to load an image, but most of them don't exist. I guess all these failing requests were producing the error. When I remove the img-Tags it's working fine, also when the requested images are existing. Thanks for your help though!!